# How to dynamically replace text between symbols and replace with a constant in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a problem where I need to search a HTML page/snippet and replace any value that is between four percentile symbols and convert to a constant variable, e.g. %%THIS_CONSTANT%% becomes THIS_CONSTANT.

Right now I am searching through the page, line by line, and I am able to find matches and replace them by using preg_match_all and preg_replace.

```
$file_scan = fopen($directory.$file, "r");    
if ($file_scan) {                                     
  while (($line = fgets($file_scan)) !== false) {
    if(preg_match_all('/\%%(.*?)\%%/', $line, $matches)){
      foreach($matches as $match){
        foreach($match as $m){
          $repair = preg_replace('/\%%(.*?)\%%/', $m, $m);
          if(preg_match('/\%%(.*?)\%%/', $m, $m)){

          } else {
            echo $repair.' '.$j;
            $j++;
          }
        }
        $lines[$i] = preg_replace('/\%%(.*?)\%%/', constant($repair), $line);
      }
    } else {
      $lines[$i] = $line;    
    }
    $i++; 
  }
  $template[$name] = implode("", $lines);
  fclose($file_scan);
}
```

What this code is not able to do is find and replace multiple matches on a single line. For instance, if there is a line with:

```
<img src="%%LOGO_IMAGE%%"><h1>%%TITLE%%</h1>
```

The above code would replace both items with the same value (TITLE). It would also give the error **couldn't find constant** on the first loop, but work correctly on the second.

This happens very rarely, but I just wish to know how to modify multiple instances on a single line just to be safe.

**Edit:**

I am able to replace the majority of the code with this:

```
$file_scan = fopen($directory.$file, "r");
if ($file_scan) {
  while (($line = fgets($file_scan)) !== false) {
    $line = preg_replace('/\%%(.*?)\%%/', '$2'.'$1', $line);
    echo $line;
  }             
fclose($file_scan);
```

My last issue is changing the replaced items to constants. Is that possible?

**Final Edit:**

With the help from Peter Bowers suggestion, I used preg_replace_callback to add the ability to change the keyword to a constant:

```
foreach($filenames as $file){
  $name = str_replace('.html', '', $file);
  $template[$name] = preg_replace_callback('/\%%(.*?)\%%/', function($matches){                 
    $matches[0] = preg_replace('/\%%(.*?)\%%/', '$1', $matches[0]);
    return constant($matches[0]);
   }, file_get_contents($directory.$file));
  }
return $template;
```

Comment: Delete all your code, take a look at the php manual about `preg_replace`, make several tries to well understand how it works (use the doc examples and play with them). You will quickly find a solution. don't touch to your pattern, you have the good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a much simpler implementation.

```
$file_scan = fopen($directory.$file, "r");    
if ($file_scan) {                                     
  $out = '';
  while (($line = fgets($file_scan)) !== false) {
    $out .= preg_replace('/\%%(.*?)\%%/', '$1', $line);
    $i++; 
  }
  $template[$name] = $out;
  fclose($file_scan);
}
```

Or, even simpler:

```
$str = file_get_contents($directory.$file);
$template[$name] = preg_replace('/\%%(.*?)\%%/', '$1', $str);
```

And, since we're going totally simple here...

```
$template[$name] = preg_replace('/\%%(.*?)\%%/', '$1', file_get_contents($directory.$file));
```

(Obviously you are losing some of your error checking capabilities as we approach the one-liner, but - hey - I was having fun... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<?php

define('TITLE', 'Title');
define('LOGO_IMAGE', 'Image');

$lines = array();

$file_scan = fopen($directory.$file, "r");    
if ($file_scan) {                                     
  while (($line = fgets($file_scan)) !== false) {
    if(preg_match_all('/\%%(.*?)\%%/', $line, $matches)){
      for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
          $line = str_replace($matches[0][$i], constant($matches[1][$i]), $line);
     }
     $lines[] = $line; 
     print_r($line);
   }
 }
}    
$template[$name] = implode("", $lines);
fclose($file_scan);

?>
```